# Need of charset in PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am using PDO to connect to database, I just want to know why I need charset if it doesn't show any error.And if i must use charset what is the correct format.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:$connstr",  $user, $password);
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

or

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know why I need charset if it doesn't show any error.

If it doesn't - well, you don't need then.

> what is the correct format.

Correct one would be to add `;charset=utf8` to your `$connstr`. But as it wont't work on the earlier versions, init command could be used just in case.